# React: Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I just started with react and I was going through one of the videos about "Handling Dynamic content in react).

So our main goal is to display three boxes using map function when we click on a button.

We Initially created State Object like this

```
state = {
    person: [
    {name: "Rohit", age: 24},
    {name: "Hariom", age: 23},
    {name: "Vaibhav", age: 58}
  ],
  someOtherState: "Untouched state",
  showPerson: false
}
```

And then we tried something like this for conditional and mapping

```
 render() {

    let person = null;

    if (this.state.showPerson) {
      person = (
        <div>
          {this.state.person.map(Person => {
            return <Person
            name={Person.name}
            age={Person.age} />
          })}
          </div>
     );
    }
```

Followed by this

```
return (

  <div className="App">
        <h1> Hi I am react App</h1>
        <button onClick={this.togglerPersonHandler}>Button</button>
        {person}
    </div>
      );
   }
}
```

Now, When I click on a button it throws following error (three times)

```
index.js:2178 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check your code at App.js:54.
    in App (at index.js:7)
```

and

```
index.js:2178 The above error occurred in the <div> component:
    in div (at App.js:52)
    in div (at App.js:63)
    in App (at index.js:7)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
```

What am I doing wrong here? (THe togglerPersonHandler simply changes the value of someOtherState). Do let me know my mistake and fix.

Comment: Can you post the code for `togglerPersonHandler()` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue is in this part:

```
{this.state.person.map(Person => { return <Person .....})
```

Don't forgot that, we write **[jsx](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)** that is syntactic sugar, it will get converted into:

```
React.createElement(type, props, children)
```

Type should be either a string for html tags, or react component.

So in your case, you are using `Person` as an argument to arrow function means its value will be each object of the `this.state.persons` array.
At the same time you are rendering `<Person />`, and Person is an object, not a valid type, that's why you are getting error:

> React.createElement: type is invalid

Solution will be, if (Person is a react component, you defined somewhere), use a different name:

```
<div>
    {
        this.state.person.map(el => (
            <Person
                key={el.name}
                name={el.name}
                age={el.age} />
            )
        )
    }
</div>
```

Also assign a unique key to each element.

Comment: Hey, That does solve my problem. I have one more questions though
If I do something like this  ` this.state.person.map(el => {  it doesn't work but when I do something like this ' this.state.person.map(el => (  ' it works. I know I am missing something, Can you please also tell the difference?

Comment: sorry, i didn't see any diff both are same, can you please explain more

Comment: `this.state.person.map(el => {` does not work but `this.state.person.map(el => (`  works. I can see the difference between **{** and **(**  but can you tell me why it does not work with this `{`

Comment: The video tutorial I am following, My instructor did something like this: 
https://imgur.com/a/bIpqb

Comment: because these are two ways of using arrow function one is `() => {return ....}` and `() => ()`, with `{}` return is required and with `()` whatever you write inside that will be returned :)

Answer (score 0):

I Agree with @Mayank Shukla. Although a simpler, less complicated way of doing this would be

```
    render() {
    let person = this.state.person.map(per => <Person key={per.name} name={per.name} age={per.age}/>);

    return (  <div className="App">
        <h1> Hi I am react App</h1>
        <button onClick={this.togglerPersonHandler}>Button</button>
        {this.state.showPerson ? person : ''}
    </div>);
}
```

}